# how to make a country clickable on jvectormap

Tags: dictionary, clickable, jvectormap

Hi I am looking to find out, how to make the countries clickable. So for example I want to be able have a country and when you click it, goes to a different page.

My code wont work

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('#map').vectorMap({
                map: 'world_en',
                color: '#4A7E2A',
                hoverColor: '#0066FF',
                hoverOpacity: 0.5,
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                regionsSelectable: true,
                onRegionClick: function(event, code) 
                {
                    if (code === 'ID') {
                        window.location = 'index.php?id=Ireland'
                    }
                    else if (code === 'RUSSIA') {
                        window.location = 'index.php?id=Russia'
                    }
                    else if (code === 'rp') {
                        window.location = 'index.php?id=4'
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. You should end your statements inside of the if conditions with a `;`, but it didn't prevent it from working for me in Chrome. What browser are you using? Does the map render, just the click event on the region isn't changing the page as you expect? Is there anything other than "won't work" that you can describe? Do you see any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like you got the `code` values wrong.

`code` for `Ireland` is `IE`, `code` for `Russia` is `RU`, I don't know what `rp` is code for.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/143/) I made for other jVectorMap related questions, with modifications to suit your questions. Play with it and come back with any questions you may still have.